# Get value of input type=date inside modal

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem in getting the value of `input` tag with a type of `date` which is place inside a modal. I'm trying to get this value using javascript. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'single_collection' %}">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputSQAID" class="col-sm-3 control-label">SQA Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
       <input type="hidden" name="sqa_name" id="sqa_name" value="{{ collectionlist.sqa_name }}">
      </div>
     </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fromdate2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">From:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fromdate2" id="fromdate2" max="{% now 'Y-m-d' %}" required>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="s_dl" id="s_dl" onclick="single_c()">Download</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's my javascript code, I'm just trying to display the value of the date from the `input [type=date]`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function single_c(){
        var dates2 = document.getElementById('fromdate2').value;
        document.write(dates2)
    }
</script>
```

I tried to place the input tag outside the modal then it is working but when I put it back inside the modal it is not working. Any work around in here.

Comment: The code works fine . It executing the `document.write()` without any error .

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama yes sir, but why is it not displaying the selected dates? this input tag is inside a modal sir. .

Comment: Where do you want to display the selected date ? @N.Omugs

Comment: Try with `type="button"`, `submit` actually submits the form. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama I'am just displaying the date for testing sir if it is getting the selected date

Comment: @tevemadar still not getting the value of the selected date sir. .

Comment: sorry , but not getting what you are trying to say . @N.Omugs

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama sorry sir, I just want to get the value of my input tag. Im just using `document.write()` to know if I'am getting the value. .

Answer (score 0):

Your input does not have "value" property.
So you need to add "value" property to input,

And you need to call function single_c()

this function after how you type some text in input

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
var date = "please enter a date";

dates.addEventListener('input',(e) => {
    date = e.target.value
})

function single_c(){
    document.write(date)
}
```

Comment: It display `null` value

Comment: that is the default value. If you select a date, the date will show up. I changed the code a bit so you get some kind of an error message

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.

The main issue here is that if you have an id to target the value, the id must have the same name as the name attribute. I.e if you have an `id="CheckingDate"`, your `name="CheckingDate"` else it won't work.